# MVC Partial View render as a view after a post

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Good day
I have an Index page that display 2 partialviews on 2 tabs. Each tab has a submit button on it, when the submit button is clicked then it hits the controller and the controller does some process and return a populated model for that partialview, but the partialview is renderd as a view on its own.

`Index.chtml` page

```
...
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="float:left">
    <div >
        <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#IdentifyPerson" data-toggle="tab" class=""><strong>Identify Person</strong></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#PersonInformation" data-toggle="tab" class=""><strong>Person Information</strong></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
    <div id="IdentifyPerson" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        @Html.Partial("IdentifyPerson")
    </div>
    <div id="PersonInformation" class="tab-pane fade">
        @Html.Partial("PersonInformation")
    </div>
</div>
```

`HomeCntroller.cs` page

```
[AuthorizeUser]
   public ActionResult Index(string ActionValue)
   {
       return View();
   }

   [HttpGet]
   [AuthorizeUser]
   public ActionResult IdentifyPerson()
   {
       return View();
   }

   [HttpPost]
   [AuthorizeUser]
   public ActionResult IdentifyPerson(ViewModel_IdentifyPerson model)
   {
       // do populate model
       return View(model);
   }
```

any advice on fixing this?

**Identify Person page**
[image: Identify Person]

**Person Information page**
[image: Person Information here]

Comment: You need to use ajax to submit the form if you want to stay on the same page.

Comment: it's doing what it's supposed to do.Use `ajax` not `form submit`

Comment: ok thanx but can you use ajax on a razor page

Comment: Use `return PartialView(model);` Instead of  `return View(model);`

Answer (score 1):

you may be using **Form** rather than **ajax form**. so you need to use ajax form to stay on same page.

In **IdentifyPerson** tab

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("IdentifyPerson", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "IdentifyPerson" , InsertionMode= InsertionMode.Replace}))
{
    //Other stuff
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

and In **PersonInformation** tab

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("IdentifyPerson", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "PersonInformation", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    //Other stuff
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

you need to include this Js file
`<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>` on your view
and also change your return type `PartialView` to in action

```
[HttpPost]
    [AuthorizeUser]
    public ActionResult IdentifyPerson(ViewModel_IdentifyPerson model)
    {
        // do populate model
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Comment: I implemented your recommendations, but I still get the same result

Comment: @ArnoDT: you need to include this Js file
`<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>` on your view

Comment: i did include it, but now i get the raw HTML without any CSS and any other script

Answer (score 0):

If You using bootstrap,You can simply wrap Your Form in Bootstrap modal window as a partial view

Comment: I am using bootstrap as my base CSS file, how do I implement this

Comment: is it essential to display two forms on site at once? otherwise it could by hidden by default and showing separately on click event ...

Comment: for it needs to be a tabbed page i think, because page one gets user input then that input is used to hit a db and then the result is displayed on the first page and it populates a model for page two. after this the other tabs need to be enabled then one must be able to go to the first page with out inputting the information again